# jQuery count the number of classes and stop to specific class

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="cal-av">
  <div>available</div>
</div>
<div class="cal-av">
  <div>available</div>
</div>
<div class="cal-av">
  <div>available</div>
</div>
<div class="cal-nc">
  <div> not available</div>
</div>
<div class="cal-av end">
  <div>available</div>
</div>
<div class="cal-av">
  <div>available</div>
</div>
<div class="cal-av">
  <div>available</div>
</div>
```

It is possible to count the total number of the class "cal-av"  starting with the class ".cal-av" and end with ".cal-av.end" The expected result should be 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [.prevall()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to count element.

> Description: Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

When you use `.prevall()` just add one because the end selector is not counted on the count

```js
var count = $( ".cal-av.end" ).prevAll(".cal-av").length;

console.log(count + 1 ) // add one since the last selected itself is not included in the count
$('.cal-av').eq(3).css("color","red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div class="cal-nc">
   <div> not available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av end">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Im sorry but it is not working on my end. Only showing 1

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.cal-av').each(function(index){ //loop through all .cal-av
    if ($(this).is('.cal-av.end')){ // check if this is the one you're looking for
      console.log(index+1); //plus 1 since index is zero based
      return false;  //stop the loop
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div class="cal-nc">
   <div> not available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av end">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Working as it should. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/4ocu2ahu/

```js
var count = 0;
$('.cal-av').each(function(){
 count++;
 if($(this).hasClass('end')){
   return false; 
  }
});

console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
 </div>
 <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
 </div>
 <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
 </div>
 <div class="cal-nc">
   <div> not available</div>
 </div>
 <div  class="cal-av end">
   <div>available</div>
 </div>
 <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
 </div>
 <div  class="cal-av">
   <div>available</div>
 </div>
```